# Why does Bazel build generate .pic.o and .pic.d files, and what's their purpose?

Tags: compilation, bazel

I use bazel to build a small c++ program, program directory structure is like this

```
.
├── bazel-bin -> /data/.cache/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin
├── bazel-main -> /data/.cache/execroot/__main__
├── bazel-out -> /data/.cache/execroot/__main__/bazel-out
├── bazel-testlogs -> /data/.cache/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs
├── BUILD
├── library
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── foo.cc
│   └── foo.h
├── main.cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

this is BUILD file in library

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cc"],
    hdrs = ["foo.h"]
)
```

this is BUILD file in main directory

```
cc_binary(
    name = "myapp",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//library:foo",
    ],

)
```

the structure of directory bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin is like this

```
   .
    ├── library
    │   ├── libfoo.a
    │   ├── libfoo.a-2.params
    │   ├── libfoo.so
    │   ├── libfoo.so-2.params
    │   └── _objs
    │       └── foo
    │           ├── foo.pic.d
    │           └── foo.pic.o
    ├── myapp
    ├── myapp-2.params
    ├── myapp.runfiles
    │   ├── __main__
    │   │   └── myapp -> /data/.cache/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/myapp
    │   └── MANIFEST
    ├── myapp.runfiles_manifest
    └── _objs
        └── myapp
            ├── main.pic.d
            └── main.pic.o
```

I know that pid stands for position independent code. I want to know whether Bazel uses the libfoo.a or foo.pic.o when linking with main, and why bazel generates these two types of files, libfoo.xx and foo.pic.xx. what's the difference between them?

when I move library directory out of main, then use local_repository in WORKSPACE to specify library foo, after bazel build, I find that there is no libfoo.xx files generated, only foo.pic.xx file can be found in bazel-out directory,

Comment: `.d` for *dependency* files, files containing source file dependencies (what header files it includes, basically). `.o` files are *object* files, the files that the compiler generates, which are then linked to form the executable program file. Please take some time to research the C and C++ build processes, how compilation and linking works, and learn about [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know what these file extension stands for, I want to know why bazel generate libfoo.a and foo.pic.o both, I think either of them can link with main right?

Comment: First of all, all build-systems saves the object files because otherwise they have to be rebuilt every time you change once source file. Doesn't matter much for a single-file library or project, but once you start building multiple files you will save quite a lot of time by not having to rebuild everything just for a small change in a single source file. And the library file is created because that's what you asked to be created.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so main is linked with foo.pic.o file , and libfoo.a and libfoo.so are just results of cc_library ?

Comment: No, you also ask Bazel to link with the library, with the `deps` directive. The object files are there to make rebuilding the library easier.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but when I move library directory out of main, then use local_repository in WORKSPACE to specify library foo, after bazel build, I find that there is no libfoo.xx files generated, only foo.pic.xx file can be found in bazel-out directory, does this suggest that main is linked with foo.pic.o file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo.pic.o`, an object file, and `foo.pic.d`, a dependency file, are the outputs of compiling `foo.cc`. Traditionally, object files are put into `ar` archives, which can be liked into top-level shared libraries or binaries. If you `bazel build` a `cc_library` rule directly, Bazel will compile the sources files within it and produce an `ar` archive. However, modern linkers commonly used on Linux can take the object files directly without needing the archive indirection. Bazel detects this linker feature and uses it to avoid archives if possible. In the example in the question, building only the top-level `myapp` does not require `libfoo.a` to be created.